# C++ glm::mix error

Tags: c++, glm-math

I have this line of code with the following libraries

- gl\glew.h
- gl\GL.h
- gl\glu.h
- gl\wglew.h
- glm/glm.hpp
- glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp
- glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp
- glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp
- glm/gtx/transform.hpp
- glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp
- glm/gtx/quaternion.hpp
- glm/gtx/compatibility.hpp

The Orientation properties are `glm::mat4` and the `fInterpolate` is a float.

```
finalJoint.Orientation = glm::mix(joint0.Orientation, joint1.Orientation, fInterpolate);
```

causing this error

> Error 3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct
>   glm::detail::tmat4x4 __cdecl glm::mix,float>(struct glm::detail::tmat4x4
>   const &,struct glm::detail::tmat4x4 const &,float const &)"
>   (??$mix@U?$tmat4x4@M@detail@glm@@M@glm@@YA?AU?$tmat4x4@M@detail@0@ABU120@0ABM@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: void __thiscall
>   saragan::cSaraganMesh::InterpolateMesh(struct keyFrame,struct
>   keyFrame,float)"
>   (?InterpolateMesh@cSaraganMesh@saragan@@QAEXUkeyFrame@@0M@Z)  D:\git\TestBed\TestBed\ObjLoader.lib(cSaraganMesh.obj)  TestBed

I have tried with `glm:quat` but I get the same error; I have it working in another project but cannot find the difference, same libraries and preprocessors in the same order?

Comment: @BenjaminBannier there should not be anything to link, it's a header only lib

Comment: @Saragan I can't find the definition for the mat mix but could you post the error that you get when you try to mix quats? Because maybe you need to adjust the mix float type (half, float or double might need to match the hquat, quat or dquat type) although the docs say you shouldn't have to

Comment: hmmm the error for quat went away when regarding to mat4... will post main fix/workaround in main comment for opinion

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your include files are not in the same directory?

Usually with unresolved external symbols error, you declare the variable in the header as:

```
extern int x;
```

and then in the cpp file you'd define it.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting enough my issue went away when using quats again....i think there is something funny when using mat4 and mix

```
glm::quat joint0Orientation = glm::toQuat(joint0.Orientation);
glm::quat joint1Orientation = glm::toQuat(joint1.Orientation);

glm::quat Final = glm::mix(joint0Orientation, joint1Orientation, fInterpolate);
finalJoint.Orientation = glm::toMat4(Final);
```

The above seemed to fix my issue though its in-efficient, can anyone see what caused the initial issue? or suspect what the problem was just for clarity?